# Flex Hslider tooltip time while mouseovering it

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, flash-builder, flex4.5, flash

Hi currently i'm designing the player by using the flex.I want to show the time while mouseovering on the scrubber(i.e HSlider).I have tried with **Datatip** .But that is only working when i'm dragging that slider and also tried with **change** event in that slider that is also working by only clicking.

This is my code:

```
<mx:HSlider id="slider" x="160" y="376" width="387" height="42"
         enabled="true"
         change="movieSeek(event)"
         mouseDown="isScrubbing=true" 
         mouseUp="isScrubbing=false" 
         showTrackHighlight="true"
showDataTip="true"                                       styleName="customHSlider"
    useHandCursor="{fpsText.text}"
    trackHighlightSkin="@Embed(source='assets/images/track.png')" />





function movieSeek(event:Event):void
    {
      if (nsPlay == null) return;
      if (doPlay.styleName=="customButton")
      { 
        nsPlay.resume();
      }     
      slider.toolTip = "time ="+slider.value;
      nsPlay.seek(slider.value);            
    }
```

In some blogs i have that about ***mx_internal***. Is possible to get the value of the current position while mouse overing it.please suggest me.

I want it to be like this

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can create custom HSlider and listen mouseMove events, i created simple example, you may refactor and optimization it for yourself, See code:

```
package classes
{
    import flash.events.MouseEvent;
    import flash.geom.Point;

    import mx.controls.HSlider;
    import mx.controls.sliderClasses.SliderDataTip;
    import mx.core.mx_internal;
    import mx.formatters.NumberFormatter;

    use namespace mx_internal;

    public class HSliderCustom extends HSlider
    {

        private var _rollOver:Boolean = false;
        private var _thumbActivity:Boolean = false;

        public function HSliderCustom()
        {
            super();
        }

        //
        //  Handlers
        //

        protected function onRollOutHandler(event:MouseEvent):void
        {
            _rollOver = false;

            destroyMovieHandler();

            if (!_thumbActivity)
            {
                if (mx_internal::dataTip)
                {
                    systemManager.toolTipChildren.removeChild(mx_internal::dataTip);
                    mx_internal::dataTip = null;
                }
            }
        }

        protected function onRollOverHandler(event:MouseEvent):void
        {
            _rollOver = true;

            addMovieHandler();
        }

        protected function onMouseMoveHandler(event:MouseEvent):void
        {
            var p:Point = new Point(event.localX, event.localY);
            var p_global:Point = event.target.localToGlobal(p);
            var p_content:Point = globalToContent(p_global);

            onRollOverTooltip(p_content.x, p_content.y);
        }

        mx_internal function addMovieHandler():void
        {
            if (!hasEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_MOVE))
                addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_MOVE, onMouseMoveHandler, false, 0, true);
        }

        mx_internal function destroyMovieHandler():void
        {
            if (hasEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_MOVE))
            {
                removeEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_MOVE, onMouseMoveHandler);
            }
        }

        //
        //  Overriden methods
        //

        override protected function childrenCreated():void
        {
            super.childrenCreated();

            addEventListener(MouseEvent.ROLL_OVER, onRollOverHandler, false, 0, true);
            addEventListener(MouseEvent.ROLL_OUT, onRollOutHandler, false, 0, true);

        }

        override mx_internal function onThumbMove(thumb:Object):void
        {
            destroyMovieHandler();

            _thumbActivity = true;

            super.mx_internal::onThumbMove( thumb );
        }

        override mx_internal function onThumbRelease(thumb:Object):void
        {
            super.mx_internal::onThumbRelease( thumb );

            if (_rollOver)
            {
                addMovieHandler();
            }

            _thumbActivity = false;
        }

        //
        //  New methods
        //

        protected function onRollOverTooltip(localX:Number, localY:Number):void
        {
            if (showDataTip)
            {

                // Setup number formatter
                var dataFormatter:NumberFormatter = new NumberFormatter();
                dataFormatter.precision = getStyle("dataTipPrecision");

                if (!mx_internal::dataTip)
                {
                    mx_internal::dataTip = SliderDataTip(new sliderDataTipClass());
                    systemManager.toolTipChildren.addChild(mx_internal::dataTip);

                    var dataTipStyleName:String = getStyle("dataTipStyleName");
                    if (dataTipStyleName)
                    {
                        mx_internal::dataTip.styleName = dataTipStyleName;
                    }
                }

                var formattedVal:String;
                if (dataTipFormatFunction != null)
                {
                    formattedVal = this.dataTipFormatFunction(
                        mx_internal::getValueFromX(localX));
                }
                else
                {
                    formattedVal = dataFormatter.format(mx_internal::getValueFromX(localX));
                }

                mx_internal::dataTip.text = formattedVal;

                mx_internal::dataTip.validateNow();
                mx_internal::dataTip.setActualSize(mx_internal::dataTip.getExplicitOrMeasuredWidth(),mx_internal::dataTip.getExplicitOrMeasuredHeight());
                //mx_internal::positionDataTip(thumb);
            }
            mx_internal::keyInteraction = false;

            /*
            var event:SliderEvent = new SliderEvent(SliderEvent.THUMB_PRESS);
            event.value = getValueFromX(thumb.xPosition);;
            event.thumbIndex = thumb.thumbIndex;
            dispatchEvent(event);
            */

            var o:Point = new Point(localX, localY);
            var r:Point = localToGlobal(o);
            r = mx_internal::dataTip.parent.globalToLocal(r);

            mx_internal::dataTip.x = r.x < 0 ? 0 : r.x - mx_internal::dataTip.width/2;
            mx_internal::dataTip.y = y - mx_internal::dataTip.height;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks for your response Ilya. We have tried the above code but i got following errors.                                                         Call to a possibly undefined method dataTipFormatFunction           Call to a possibly undefined method sliderDataTipClass and     Access of undefined property dataTipFormatFunction. Can you suggest me to resolve these problems

Comment: i'm also using FB 4.6 only

Comment: Try to create new project with only my class and test it.

Comment: if i use only your class i got some error                             "A file found in a source-path must have the same package structure '', as the definition's package, 'classes'"

Comment: create new folder (package) with name - classes in your src root folder and place my class in it;

Answer (score 0):

Check for mouseOver event on the slider.

Comment: Yes mouseover event can give the solution but the problem is have to calculate the slider time while mouseovering it

Answer (score 0):

Check the [dataTipFormatFunction](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/mx/controls/sliderClasses/Slider.html#dataTipFormatFunction)

```
mySlider.dataTipFormatFunction = function(value:Number):String { 
    return formatTime(value); 
}

private function formatTime(value:Number) {
    return "00:00";
}
```

[Here is a great example](http://www.codebelt.com/actionscript-3/as3-convert-seconds-to-hours-minutes-seconds/) of how to convert seconds to hours, minutes and seconds.

*I know it's been over a year since this question was posted, but this helped me to the extend that I thought it may be of help to others who have the same challenge*